# Executing javascript function when h:panelGrid is reRendered

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I want to call `javascript` function when `panelGrid` was `reRenderd`.
The binding property of the panelGrid is set to a backinbBean-property holding the dynamic content which will be created when clicking on an element in a rich faces tree.
The relevant code of xhtml file:

```html
<rich:tree id="mainTree" switchType="server" toggleOnClick="false"
    nodeFace="#{item.type}" value="#{TreeController.treeView}" var="item">
    <rich:treeNode iconLeaf="/images/form_General.png" id="node"
        icon="/images/form_General.png" type="PlainForm"
        nodeClass="#{item.selected?'rich-tree-node-selected':''}">      
        <a4j:commandLink value="#{item.name}" style="display: block;"
            reRender=":formpanel,mainTree">
            <a4j:actionparam name="activeNodeId" value="#{item.id}"
                assignTo="#{TreeController.activeNodeId}" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
...
<h:panelGrid id="contentHolder" binding="#{Controller.panelContent}"
    columns="1" reRender="formularContainerTable" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The javascript function will add some `ondbclick` events to some of the dynamically generated fields within the panelContent but I have no clue how to call that javascript function when the panelContent is reRenderd.

I have search the internet for an answer but could not find any suitable solution that worked.

Comment: I am unable to see `rich:panelgrid` where is it?

Comment: use `onclick` or `oncomplete` on `commandLink` for JS execute.

Comment: according to the file I am working on it should be in the namespace xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html (sorry, not rich:panelGrid but h:panelGrid)

Comment: Ah!! Of course! I miss the forest for the trees. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: yes, it seems to work now. I will have to perform some test on it but it looks good. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, `<h:panelGrid>` doesn't have `reRender` attribute.

Comment: yeah, in fact I have put my rendered component in a rich:panel now but thanks for the hint!